# Postgres Automated Install

Tags: postgresql, installation

Is it possible to automatically create a database after a postgres one click install (from Enterprise DB)?

Comment: You could use the ZIP distribution, unzip it and then call `initdb` to create the database and `pg_ctl register` to install the Windows service (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the one-click installer does this directly (see http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide#noninteractive) but if you are calling this from another installer, you could start up the db afterwards and call createdb on it.

I assume you are trying to install from an installer for another program.  if so that's how I would do it.